# UK Business Visa valid in Hungary

Tags: visas, schengen, filipino-citizens, business-travel

I am a Filipino citizen and I just received my Class-C Business Visa from the United Kingdom. My question is, as my company also has an office in Hungary, would I still need to apply for a Business Visa to enter the  Schengen Area, more specifically Hungary?

Comment: Yes, for visas UK is totally independent from EU(Schengen area). You would need to apply for one.

Comment: @DumbCoder, that should be an answer

Comment: @GayotFow - One line answers will always be converted to a comment by the moderators, been told so in other stack exchange sites.

Answer (score 1):

As @DumpCoder already said in the comments, you will need a Schengen visa to visit Hungary. Having a Uk Business Visa could be helpfull for the Schengen visa application, but you will still need a separate visa.

The company office in Hungary is irrelevant, rent-a-car companies have offices all around the world, but having a visa for one of them will not allow you to visit all other countries.